# XML generation very slow and using lots of memory in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I'm generating an XML file to share data with another system. From my troubleshooting, I've found that this process is both slow and consuming lots of memory (getting lots of R14's on Heroku.)

My index method on my Jobs Controller looks like this:

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.xml {@jobs = @user.jobs.includes(job_types: [:job_lines, :job_photos])}
    format.json 
    { 
      # More code here, this part is not the problem.
    }
  end
end
```

My view (index.xml.builder) looks like this (I've removed a bunch of fields to keep the example smaller):

```
xml.instruct!
xml.jobs do
  @jobs.each do |j|
    xml.job do
      xml.id             j.id
      xml.job_number     j.job_number
      xml.registration   j.registration
      xml.name           j.name
      xml.job_types do
        j.job_types.each do |t|
          xml.job_type do
            xml.id          t.id
            xml.job_id      t.job_id
            xml.type_number t.type_number
            xml.description t.description
            xml.job_lines do
              t.job_lines.each do |l|
                xml.job_line do
                  xml.id          l.id
                  xml.line_number l.line_number
                  xml.job_type_id l.job_type_id
                  xml.line_type   l.line_type
                  xml.type_number l.type_number
                  xml.description l.description
                  xml.part_number l.part_number
                end # job_line node
              end # job_lines.each
            end # job_lines node
            xml.job_photos do
              t.job_photos.each do |p|
                xml.job_photo do
                  xml.id          p.id
                  xml.pcid        p.pcid
                  xml.job_type_id p.job_type_id
                  xml.image_url   p.image.url
                end # job_line node
              end # job_lines.each
            end # job_lines node
          end # job_type
        end # job_types.each
      end # job_types node
    end # job node
  end # @jobs.each
end # jobs node
```

The generated XML file is not small (it's about 100kB). Running on Heroku, their Scout tool tells me that this process is often taking 4-6 seconds to run. Also, despite only running 1 worker, with 4 threads (in Puma) this part of my code is consuming all my memory. In scout, I can see that it's "Max Allocations" are as high as 10M compared with my next worst method which is only 500k allocations.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Is there a more efficient (in terms of speed and memory usage) way for me to generate XML?

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

I've tried building the XML manually like this:

```
joblist.each do |j|
  result << "  <job>\n"
  result << "    <id>" << j.id.to_s << "</id>\n"
  result << "    <job_number>"    << j.job_number.to_s << "</job_number>\n"
  # Lots more lines removed
end
```

This has given me some improvements. My largest allocations is now 1.8M. I'm close to Heroku's limit (reached a max of 500MB out of the 512MB limit over 24 hours).

I am still only running 1 Worker with 4 threads.If I can I'd like to get the memory down more so I can run some more Puma Workers and Threads.

**EDIT 2**

I ended up having to do this in batches (using offset and limit) and send 5 jobs at a time. The memory usage dropped substantially when I did this. Obviously there was more calls to the controller but each was smaller and faster.

Comment: Is it an ActiveRecord you're trying to convert? Did you try :to_xml? http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_xml

Comment: Yes it is I'm basically dumping the results of @user.jobs.includes(job_types: [:job_lines, :job_photos]). It is the view that is slow rather than the controller so I'll check that out. Presumably it can be made to handle my nested includes so that the XML file is the same as my builder code?

Comment: What I was trying to imply is , first try and use the built-in methods before implementing them on your own. You can try and call :to_xml in your model in a delayed job , save it to a :text type column and display it when ready. I don't think a 100KB XML should be a problem to display , it's probably something inefficient in the way you generate it.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing to to_xml hasn't helped. Memory usage is UP slightly (about 10% overall) but the processing time is up noticeably. You can see the results visually here: http://imgur.com/uNWCKPj

Comment: You can try to build it via recursion instead of iteration , of course there is always the heavy guns of multi-thread/process to speed it up. Although this looks too lightweight to justify it.

Comment: @Ohad Dahan Can you elaborate on that please? I've also tried building the XML manually (see edit above).

Comment: let's take it offline , PM me.

Comment: I didn't think Stack Overflow supported PM's.